# Onemonth Rails tutorial gemfile won't let me bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing the one month rails tutorial, coming across small issues I can't seem to fix. I couldn't get some of the bootstrap features to work for making edits on this simple site, so thinking it was a problem with the gem being not updated, I went to the bootstrap site and  i tried to update a gem which it said was [gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'] so

In my gem file I went from just having

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

to

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'
```

also noticed the tutorial had this code in the gem file

```
group :doc do
        #bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api
   gem 'sdoc', require: false
   end
```

so I added that as well, 
bundle installed, restarted rails server
that didn't fix the problem so tried going back to what was before and got an error below..

```
   You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements.
   You specified: sdoc (~> 0.4.0) and sdoc (>= 0)
```

heres what my gem file looks like now, I am trying to bundle install and push to heroku but this error message won't let me.

GEM FILE below

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3' #it told me i had 2 versions so i commented out for now
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. 
            Read 
more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end


group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end



group :doc do
#   bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api
gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Should I just read the Rails book from Hartl for a better understanding under the hood?

Answer (score 4):

You have specified `gem 'sdoc'` twice in your Gemfile with different versions which is causing the error:

```
You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements.
You specified: sdoc (~> 0.4.0) and sdoc (>= 0)
```

See below:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
##...
##... 
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc ##<-- First
##...
##...
group :doc do
#   bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api
gem 'sdoc', require: false    ##<-- Second
end
```

Remove the one which is not required and run `bundle install`